# IOS Static tableview cell cannot be localized

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Let say, the storyboard is `Main.storyboard` and I have a `TableViewController`. I have a Static Table View with 2 sections, each with 1 row.

I created the localization file, so my project structure looks like this:

- Main.Storyboard (base)
- Main.Strings (FR)

`Main.Strings` contains all the localized string in French. The problem is, when I run the device in FR, the content did not get localized.

Here is a image of the storyboard that I'm talking about. (You can replace `label` with any text).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc2lP.png)

Note: It worked before in Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0. However, once I upgraded to Xcode 9 with Swift 4.0, it doesn't seem to work.

Fixed:

- Xcode bugged. Started a new storyboard and everything seems to work perfectly...

Comment: Is everything else being localized?

Comment: Yes. Everything else inside the storyboard is localized, except for that two static cell.

Comment: Xcode 10 with swift 4?

Comment: Sorry, it's Xcode 9 with Swift 4. MY BAD!

Comment: You can use the "Localize_Swift" library for localization

Answer (score 0):

Localizing storyboard files is difficult to maintain to my opinion. I recommend placing all your translations in a single `Localizable.strings` file and setting the localizations programmatically in the view controllers.

You can make things easier with the following extension:

```
extension String {

    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }

}
```

If you then define your translations as global constants like:

```
class Texts {

    class MyViewController {

        static let title = "My Title".localized
        static let editLabel = "Edit your text".localized
        static let editTextFieldPlaceholder = "Sample text".localized
        static let editButtonTitle = "Edit".localized

    }

}
```

You can simply set your localizations for a view controller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Localization
    self.title = Texts.MyViewController.title
    self.editLabel.text = Texts.MyViewController.editLabel
    self.editTextField.placeholder = Texts.MyViewController.editTextFieldPlaceholder
    self.editButton.setTitle(Texts.MyViewController.editButtonTitle, for: .normal)
}
```

This way, your localizations will become much more structured and maintainable. Also, you do not need to retranslate the whole storyboard any time you change a single element. You can even [localize plurals](https://crunchybagel.com/localizing-plurals-in-ios-development/), which is just not possible with simple storyboard localization.

Comment: maintainable? really?